# Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file, databinding with observablefield

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want my view visibility to be dependent on condition behaviour so I am using ObservableField and with databinding trying to change view visibility but getting issue like "Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file.  InputType is missing it"

Code:

```
Kotlin File

var showView: ObservableField<Boolean>? = ObservableField(false)

//API call response
showView.set(true)


Layout File:

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.showView ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
```

How to apply databinding with Observablefield of type boolean? I have used it for string text also and it's working but not working with boolean conditional statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if that's the case here, but this error message is usually displayed when you reference a type in your binding expressions that hasn't been declared in the `<data>` section of your layout. The same way you declare the `View` type as an import, you should declare the type `InputType`.

```xml
<data>
    <!-- Maybe an import for InputType is missing here? -->
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.yourpackage.YourViewModel"/>
</data>
```

Comment: No I have decalred viewModel in <data> section

Comment: But the viewmodel is not the issue here. The problem seems to be that the type called `InputType` is missing from your imports. Are you sure you have declared a valid import for it?

Comment: Ohh yes got it. I forgot to import InputType, such small mistake. thank you for the answer